# multiple (R) plotly figures generated in a Rmarkdown (knitr chunk) document

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, plotly

I try to create multiple plotly figures in a Rmarkdown document using loop or lapply.

The R script:

```
require(plotly)
data(iris)
b <- lapply(setdiff(names(iris), c("Sepal.Length","Species")),
            function(x) {
              plot_ly(iris, 
                      x = iris[["Sepal.Length"]],
                      y = iris[[x]], 
                      mode = "markers")
            })
print(b)
```

works well, but it fails when included in a knitr chunk:

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r,results='asis'}
require(plotly)
data(iris)
b <- lapply(setdiff(names(iris), c("Sepal.Length","Species")),
            function(x) {
              plot_ly(iris, 
                      x = iris[["Sepal.Length"]],
                      y = iris[[x]], 
                      mode = "markers")
            })
print(b)
```
````

I tried replacing `print(b)` with a combination of `lapply` `eval` and `parse` but only the last figure was displayed.

I suspect a scoping/environment issue but I cannot find any solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of `print(b)`, put `b` in `htmltools::tagList()`, e.g.

````
```{r}
library(plotly)

b <- lapply(
  setdiff(names(iris),
          c("Sepal.Length","Species")),
  function(x) {
    plot_ly(iris, 
            x = iris[["Sepal.Length"]],
            y = iris[[x]], 
            mode = "markers")
  }
)

htmltools::tagList(b)
```
````

**Note:** Before Plotly v4 it was necessary to convert the Plotly objects to htmlwidgets using Plotly's `as.widget()` function. As of Plotly v4 they are htmlwiget objects by default.

For people who are interested in the technical background, you may see [this blog post of mine](https://yihui.org/en/2017/06/top-level-r-expressions/). In short, only *top-level* expressions get printed.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But it does not work. I see warning messages :

Comment: ## Warning in charToRaw(text): argument should be string with length 1 (approx. transl.)

Comment: It looks like the function tagList() takes data of the plots as input instead of the generated figures (in js).

Comment: I have updated my answer. Basically you need `as.widget()` from the development version of **plotly**.

Answer (score 3):

I found a "dirty" solution by using temp file and kniting it :

````
```{r,echo=FALSE}
mytempfile<-tempfile()
write("```{r graphlist,echo=FALSE}\n",file=mytempfile)
write(paste("p[[",1:length(p),"]]"),file=mytempfile,append = TRUE)
write("\n```",file=mytempfile,append = TRUE)
```

`r knit_child(mytempfile, quiet=T)`
````

But it's unsatisfactory.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone struggling with a loop, here's what worked for me.

```
p=list()
for (n in 1:3){
  p[[n]] <- plot_ly(x = 1:100, y = rnorm(100)+n, mode = 'lines', type="scatter")
}
htmltools::tagList(p)
```

I.e. it doesn't matter if the list `p` is created in a loop or lapply, etc. as long as you call `htmltools::tagList` outside the loop.

Thanks to Yihui for helping me get there and for immense work developing and helping with these tools.